# How to change the size of window.open() (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, popup

I need to have the size of 800x800 of the popup window.
I changed the size to 200, 400, 700, etc., but it doesn't change the size.
It just shows a small popup window and the size never changes (no error in console).
Would you please let me know how to change the size?
The code I'm using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.popup').click(function() {
     var popupWindow = window.open($(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=800,width=800,scrollbars=yes');
     if (window.focus)
     {
       popupWindow.focus();
     }
     return false;
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the stackoverflow sandbox does not support window.open, so if the example is not working correctly, try the codesandbox link below.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document
    .getElementById("button-vanilla")
    .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("vanilla");
      window.open(
        "https://www.pocketserver.org/",
        "Pocket Server",
        "height=800,width=800,resizable,scrollbars,status"
      );
    });
});


(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button-jquery").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("jQuery");
      window.open(
        "https://www.pocketserver.org/",
        "Pocket Server",
        "height=800,width=800,resizable,scrollbars,status"
      );
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" id="button-jquery">Click jQuery</div>
    <br>
    <a href="#" id="button-vanilla">Click Vanilla</div>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

A working example can be found here using vanilla Javascript and jQuery.

// https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-minsky-uv87t?file=/src/index.js:1-269

You may need to prevent the default behavior of the popup link if it is an actual link tag using the preventDefault function.

Comment: Provide the relevant code in the answer. Demos are great but only as support for what actually exists in the answer itself. If that link were to rot this answer would be useless. Also readers shouldn't need to go off site just to review your solution

Comment: Looks like the default sandbox does not support window.open, or at least it throws an error. I will still post it, but keep the previous codesandbox link.